# What code would I place in my enter case?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I've made a switch-case where I use the up arrow key, down arrow key and enter key. However I can't think of how to put code into my enter case in which I can choose an option.

```
public static void entries()
    {
        keyPressed = Console.ReadKey(true);
        switch (keyPressed.Key)
        {

            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                if (keyPressed.Key.ToString() == "DownArrow")// selects the curitem when the down arrow key is pressed
                {
                    curItem++;
                    if (curItem > menuItems.Length - 1) curItem = 0;
                }
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                if (keyPressed.Key.ToString() == "UpArrow")// selects the curitem when the up arrow key is pressed
                {
                    curItem--;
                    if (curItem < 0) curItem = Convert.ToInt16(menuItems.Length - 1);

                }
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                if (keyPressed.Key.ToString() == "Enter")// when enter is pressed it will go to one of the choices 
                {

                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wait, what? What does the Enter key do in your program?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish a bit more? ie, what should the Enter key do when pressed?

Comment: Well, you could make it like..  do the thing that curItem is supposed to do.  am I not understanding?

Comment: According to the comment in the code, you should "go to one of the choices."  Now, what does that mean?

Comment: Ive got 5 options to choose from, the enter key is to select the option and show that option after console.clear(). I was thinking of an if statement inside an if statement.

Comment: Doing a `ToString()` on an enumeration and then comparing it the string representation of the enum value is wasteful and error prone. Just use the enum value like you do in each `case`. Except you don't need the `if` statements because the value of the `keyPressed.Key` already have been checked in the `switch` statement.

Comment: On a side note, why do you check the key pressed twice? `switch/case` then `if`

Comment: Okay Martin and Jb i understand what you meant about the key press, I figured it out as well. Just have to place my choice voids inside the enter case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea about nesting `if` statements is correct, or having another switch.  I would probably re-factor this into another function though:

```
case ConsoleKey.Enter:
   chooseOption(curItem);
   break;
```

...

```
void chooseOption(int item)
{
   switch(item)
   {
      case 1:
        //Do item 1
        break;
      case 2:
        //Do item 2
        break;
      case 3:
        //Do item 3
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but the weird thing is the the firstchoice when i run the app doesnt work, the second choice somehow is the firstchoice and so on for the rest of the choices.

Comment: is curItem 0 based?  If so, start with `case 0:` - You might want to use an `enum` for your options instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment. here is how you can display the current item inside the menuItems array. I'm assuming menuItems holds some strings or ints or something that can be easily written to the console.

```
case ConsoleKey.Enter:
// when enter is pressed it will go to one of the choices 
   Console.Clear();
   Console.WriteLine(menuItems[curItem]);
   break;
```

Comment: well ive got the options displayed, just need to be able to select the option

Comment: @user1073429 I don't understand, isn't selecting the option what the up/down arrows do?

Comment: yeah they do but your saying in the code provided to write the options to the screen, i have this already. The up and down arrow keys work fine.

Comment: When i mean selecting the option, i mean when i press enter a new screen shows. Like the option is to add an entry, when i select the option it shows the adding an entry screen. I have this working but option 1 doesnt work, option 2 is option 1, option 3 is option 2 and so on.

Comment: right, ok. so if the up/down arrows select which option. and the enter key displays the option. what else do you need to do? i'm missing something here.

Comment: ah, i see. right, use Mike's answer, but make the first case be case 0. because you curItem is zero based